# Datediff for datetime in different time zones

Tags: coldfusion, datediff, gmt

UPDATED

I need to get the hour and minute difference between two datetimes that are in different time zones.

I have the datetime in MySQL, and the offset from GMT, of the locations in MySQL.

What I have tried:

```
<cfset departure = CreateDateTime(2017,01,27,21,00,00)> <!--- (this time zone is +2) --->
<cfset arrival = CreateDateTime(2017,01,28,06,40,00)> <!--- (this time zone is -5) --->
<cfset depart_timezone = 2>
<cfset arrive_timezone = -5>

<cfset difference = datediff("h",departure,arrival)><!--- get the difference in hours --->

<cfset timezonedif = depart_timezone - arrive_timezone><!--- get the difference between the time zones (answer should be 7)--->
<cfset duration = difference + timezonedif><!--- add the time zone difference to the flight difference --->

<cfoutput>          
(Duration: #duration# hours)<br>
</cfoutput>
```

This returns 16 hours which is not correct. The difference should be 15 hours and 40 minutes. Help will be appreciated. Been at this for hours.

Comment: That is correct. The difference between those times you provided is 9 hours. datediff wont give you the minutes when you use 'h' as it checks hours only. If you want to allow for the time zone then you will need to calculate the actual time then get the difference. It can't guess that these are different zones. A start would be to dateAdd() the time zone to the time and then pass it. Or DateConvert() to utc and pass it.

Comment: Updated my question and tried the DateAdd, but still not getting the correct result.

Comment: I mentioned in my last comment why the minutes are not returned. Using 'h' will only return hours rounded up or down. So 16 is again correct. You will need to date diff using minutes or seconds and work out how many hours and minutes from this total. Standard minute to hours conversion.

Comment: Driving me crazy. How to display the hours and minutes from a DateDiff?

    `<cfset departure = CreateDateTime(2017,01,27,21,00,00)> <!--- (this time zone is +2) --->
    <cfset arrival = CreateDateTime(2017,01,28,06,40,00)> <!--- (this time zone is -5) --->

    <cfset differencehours = DateDiff("H",departure,arrival)>
    <cfset differenceminutes = DateDiff("n",departure,arrival)>`

This not working as expected.

Comment: (Edit) *I have the datetime in MySQL and the GMT of the location in MySQL* Do not quite follow that. Do you mean you are storing all date and time values in GMT/UTC, plus the offset for the two time zones in separate columns?  RE: *The difference should be 15 hours* Why do you think it should be 15?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing things in the wrong order.

You need to get the correct date/times - so add / remove the timezone difference

```
<cfset departure = CreateDateTime(2017,01,27,21,00,00)> <!--- (this time zone is +2) --->
<cfset arrival = CreateDateTime(2017,01,28,06,40,00)> <!--- (this time zone is -5) --->
<cfset depart_timezone = -2>
<cfset arrive_timezone = 5>

<cfset tzDeparture = DateAdd('h',depart_timezone,departure)>
<cfset tzArrival = DateAdd('h',arrive_timezone,arrival)>
```

Then get the total amount of difference in minutes

```
<cfset difference = datediff("n",tzDeparture,tzArrival)>
```

Then just do the math to convert minutes to hours & minutes

```
<cfoutput>    
    Duration Total Mins: #difference#<br>
    Duration Hours: #int(difference/60)#<br>
    Duration Mins: #difference MOD 60#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

> Output:
>
> Duration Total Mins: 1000
>
> Duration Hours: 16
>
> Duration Mins: 40

You can see an example here: http://trycf.com/gist/26f5bce31db7787f4591317b7360ceb7/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: *You are doing things in the wrong order.* If both values are stored in UTC, either way would work. Just take the dateDiff of the original values. Then add in the timezone offsets (though all in minutes, not hours).